# Why aren’t my two values comparing correctly?

Tags: javascript

I have objects that I am trying to compare their values and make a function happen if one value is greater than the other. But My code seems to be wrong because even though the value is greater than the other, it still console logs "false" instead of true. I even console logged the value to check if it was greater and it was. Here's my code.

```
var clicks1 = 0;

function onClick() {
    clicks1 += 1;
    
    document.getElementById("clicks1").innerHTML = clicks1;
    document.getElementById("clicks1").value = clicks1;

    var clicks2 = 0;

    function onClick() {
        clicks2 += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks2").innerHTML = clicks2;
        document.getElementById("clicks2").value = clicks2;

        playbutton.onclick = function () {
            const click1var = document.getElementById("clicks1").value
            const click2var = document.getElementById("clicks2").value

            console.log(click1var)    //Console shows 3
            console.log(click2var)    //Console shows 1

            if (click1var < click2var) {
                console.log('true')
            } else {
                console.log('false')  //Console shows false.  
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please format this code. It is incredibly difficult to read as is.

Comment: So you are wondering why 3 < 1 is false? BTW: you should convert strings to number when you want to compare numbers. For one digit it doesn't matter, but it does when you can get multi-digit numbers.

Comment: But everything seems to work fine. Three is not less than one (false) ..

Answer (score 0):

click1var is 3
click2var is 1

if (click1var < click2var){ // are you asking if 3 is lower than 1 (FALSE)

then it will go to the else.